# Multi Company Restriction in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, enterprise, odoo-9

Good Day!,
I have an Odoo 9 Enterprise which is a Multi Company setup
I have a Company A, B,C in which customer can Bought some Items
for Example Customer X is a customer in Company A, but Customer X can bought an Item in Company B and C with the Pricelist of Company A.
But a Restriction occur when creating an Sales Order.

the Error is this

> The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.
>
> (Document type: product.pricelist, Operation: read)

At first I thought it was a Access Rights but when I add the Model and make it read, write enable to a certain group it didnt effect the Access Rights, and for further checking of Odoo it seems the Multi Company has an effect in my case with every Pricelist I define the Company.

How can I remove the Restriction on the Model or there is another way to give a sudo right to a model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When Multi-Company is enabled, then automatically the below tick box will be enabled,

**Share product to all companies**

It Indicates, if a product is created in main company, then it will be listed in all sub company, i.e child_of. So cut the link, the product will not be shared among your sub company